# Facebook Like button freezes page when loading

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, facebook-like

I have read a number of posts about how to prevent the like button from ruining your page load times but everything I have tried has had no effect.

I have put the code at the bottom of my page as suggested in another post but it has no effect:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

The page actually freezes for about 2 seconds when it comes to render this code.

Does anyone have a solution? I think the only option I'm going to be left with is to remove it from my site :(

Comment: Removing it from your site sounds like a good idea :p

Comment: Are you using the XFBML like button code? Can you use the HTML5 div code instead? If you are using the header `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`? if you aren't using the XFBML code try dropping `#xfbml=1` from the url.